# Spring Integration flow for processing/sending email is taking hours for some of the messages

Tags: smtp, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I have spring integration app that transforms the messages using Freemarker and sends message to SMTP server. It was working fine in production for almost an year. 
The process itself is not huge, message-driven-channel-adapter reads the message, freemarker transforms the message and EmailAdapter sends the email.

It used to take around 100ms for sending email after getting the message from MQ. However for last few weeks 10% of the messages are taking more than 12 hours to between reading the messages from MQ and getting to EmailAdapter 
 other 90% (similar) 
message are still getting processed in around 100ms.

```
<!-- Email -->
<!-- Split message into separate email messages for delivery -->
<splitter id="EmailSplitter"
    input-channel="EmailDeliveryChannel"
    output-channel="EmailDeliveryProcessChannel" method="split">
    <beans:bean
        class="com.ne.splitter.EmailSplitter">
        <beans:property name="mailSender"
            ref="MailSender" />
    </beans:bean>
</splitter>

<!-- Added task executor to handler messages in dedicated threads. Otherwise one failed email delivery will fail all split messages. -->
<channel id="EmailDeliveryProcessChannel">
    <dispatcher
        task-executor="SplitDeliveryExecutor" />
</channel>

<task:executor id="RequestTaskExecutor"
    pool-size="2-100"
    queue-capacity="500"
    keep-alive="1" />

<task:executor
    id="SplitDeliveryExecutor"
    pool-size="3-200"
    queue-capacity="1000" />

<service-activator
    input-channel="EmailDeliveryProcessChannel"
    output-channel="EmailDeliveryStatusChannel" method="send">

    <beans:bean
        class="com.ne.adapters.EmailAdapter">
        <beans:property name="mailSender"
            ref="MailSender" />
        <beans:property name="retryAttempts" value="3" />
    </beans:bean>
</service-activator>
```

Why some of the messages are stuck in the process for more than 10 hours and not timing out?

Answer (score 0):

Would be grate to turn on debug for `org.springframework.integration` category and analyze logs for steps where messages are stuck. You can gather a message history for them via `WireTap` and alert somewhere. See docs about them: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-history.

Nevertheless it seems for me that the real problem with sending emails, essentially connection to the server, so nothing is wrong with your app. It is just a throughput the provider allows you to interact with it.

You may consider to place a `QueueChannel` before email Adapter to buffer messages for future processing do not effect the whole flow and don’t block the JMS consumer thread.

Comment: Thanks @Artembilan for the quick reply.  The issue is happening only in production so I can't turn on debug also, in one of the seminars Gary Russell suggested to keep message history off in production for performance reason. So I kept it off in Production.

Comment: That’s correct. So, since we can’t debug from there, consider to buffer messages before emailing and free your main process of the network throughput bottleneck

Comment: @Artembian, won't  task-executor "SplitDeliveryExecutor" suffice for buffering the messages?  it has a queue capacity of 1000. 

Also, more than 100,000 message are getting process during the same time when around 5000 message gets delayed for almost 10 hours.
This is a real time system so I can't afford this much delay of messages. 

EmailAdapter do get SMTP connection exception at times and application marks those messages for retry but in this case thread/message is just waiting somewhere without expiring.

Any reason why threads are waiting that long and not timing out?

Comment: It's hard to answer without some debug info. You might just wait for some time to obtain connection to the email server. Also I see you have enough custom code there. I'm not sure how to help from here... Maybe there is a rejection in your thread pool executors and the JMS message is ralled back and redelivered for several times blocking other messages in queue for polling. Too much variables to wonder without enough info to analyze.